# Finding maximum value of products and sum and subtract and division for elements in array

Tags: c++, algorithm, dynamic-programming

Hi i have following problem which i want to implement:

I have two arrays **n** integers array and **n - 1** operations array

- `integers[n]` // **n integers**
- `operations[n - 1]` // **n - 1 operations (eg. + - * /)**

**numbers array is fixed while the operator array can be used in any permutation in order to get the maximum value** (Thank you @**[grek40](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5265292/grek40)**)

example 1:

given array of integers: `1 2 7 5 1 2` and array of operations: `+ + + + *`

I want to find maximum adjacent product sum subtract division i.e. `1+2+7*5+1+2 = 41`

example 2:

given array of integers: `1 3 5 6 9 10 12 14` and array of operations: `+ + * * - / /`

I want to find maximum adjacent product sum subtract division i.e. `1-3/5/6+9+10*12*14 = 1689.9`

I am beginner in dynamic programming. I am unable to figure out the recurrence relation for the following problem.

Can anyone please suggest something?

thanks!

I try to use Enumeration methods, Time complexity is n!

```
for operators in allOperators:
    op = list(operators)
    op.append(' ')
    operation = ""

    for i, number in enumerate(inputNumbers):
        count += 1
        operation += number + op[i]
    output = eval(operation)

    if output > maxOutput:
        maxOutput = output
```

Comment: As there are only 4 types of operations, number of permutations is less than `n!`.

Comment: Your code is in python, while the question is tagged C++. Please, specify the appropriate tags to prevent confusion.

Comment: So basically, the numbers array is fixed while the operator array can be used in any permutation in order to get the maximum value?

Comment: @grek40 yes! operator array any permutation get the maximum value, thanks!

Comment: Can the numbers be `0` or negative or is it only positive non-zero numbers?

Comment: @grek40 Positive rational number. (eg. 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 1, 2, 3), non-zero. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Code will better than word for this problem.The state transition equation is clear in the code.

```
import functools
test1 = (1, 2, 7, 5, 1, 2)
test2 = (1, 3, 5, 6 ,9 ,10, 12, 14)
@functools.lru_cache()
def BaseSolution(nums, add, sub, mul, div, length):
    if  add<0 or sub<0 or mul<0 or div<0 or length<0:
         return float("-inf")
    if  length == 0:
        return nums[length]
    else:
        return max(
            BaseSolution(nums, add-1, sub, mul, div, length-1) + nums[length],
            BaseSolution(nums, add, sub-1, mul, div, length-1) - nums[length],
            MulOrDivSolution(nums, add, sub, mul-1, div, length-1, '*'+str(nums[length])),
            MulOrDivSolution(nums, add, sub, mul, div-1, length-1, '/'+str(nums[length])),
            )
def MulOrDivSolution(nums, add, sub, mul, div, length, lzayVal):
    if  add<0 or sub<0 or mul<0 or div<0 or length<0:
         return float("-inf")
    if  length == 0:
        return eval( str(nums[length])+lzayVal)
    else:   
        return max(
            BaseSolution(nums, add-1, sub, mul, div, length-1) + eval( str(nums[length])+lzayVal),
            BaseSolution(nums, add, sub-1, mul, div, length-1) - eval( str(nums[length])+lzayVal),
            MulOrDivSolution(nums, add, sub, mul-1, div, length-1, '*'+str(nums[length])+lzayVal),
            MulOrDivSolution(nums, add, sub, mul, div-1, length-1, '/'+str(nums[length])+lzayVal),
            )
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(BaseSolution(test1,4,0,0,1,5))
    print(BaseSolution(test2,2,1,2,2,7))
```

Comment: Are you sure that your code is a suitable solution without any explanation?

Comment: @grek40 sorry,i don't know which part is confuse and need explanation.The only trick part is special case for multiplication and division.Just start from addition and subtraction,then you will find the state transition equation.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow similar approach as this question :

[Given a list of integer numbers, a list of symbols [+,-,*,/] and a target number N](https://www.careercup.com/question?id=15466752) ,

Only difference is it talks about matching the number N, You can find Maximum sum.

The idea here is to generate combinations of the operators as long as the length of the array.

1. You can use Hashmap to store operator and count. That way while building your expression, you can keep track of count for each operator. `map<operator, count>`
2. Write separate Function to solve the expression. `Getresult(expression)`
3. Calculate all combination using numbers and operators using `std::next_permutation:`
4. Iterate through list of numbers :
5. Get result for each expression
6. Track `current_max` , and `expression_max` for max.
7. Finally Return `current_max` and `expression_max`